# No items in VS Toolbox, IDE crashes when adding items to toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm at a loss.
I'm on win7 x64.

If I open up your basic winform app the toolbox is empty.
If I try to add an item to the tool box the app crashes, even if I start it from the command line with /safemode

I've tried /safemode, /resetsettings, /resetskippkgs
I've deleted my .tbd files
I've uninstalled and re-installed both .net 3.5 and VS2008

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party controls installed that register themselves in the toolbox?